# Reordering Entries

Tags: low-reorder

I know this is super simple, because I have done it before. I need to reorder my entries (ex: newsletters) by dragging them into the correct order, rather than assigning a new number for each entry.

I cannot remember how I did it before! When I go to the Reorder Entries page, it doesn't do anything.

Screen shot:
[image: This is what I see when I go to Reorder Assets. Nothing is "clickable."]

Comment: Have you got Low Reorder installed? What version? Is there perhaps a JavaScript error? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Sorry Low, I missed your comment when I posted the answer below. Low's question is leading you in the right direction. I experienced a drag-drop issue with Low Reorder and I believe it was related to a JS error. There's also the possibility that you have a conflicting add-on that is trying to control the CP user interface - a control panel skin.

Comment: Thank you both for your feedback! I didn't realize it had been answered until now (because I still have the same problem). I don't think that I have any additional add-ons or modules.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to control the order of entries is to use Low Reorder. It's a $35 add-on but well worth the price.

After this is installed, you can create a reorder set of your newsletter entries by going to Add Ons > Modules > Low Reorder.

When you want to output a reordered list, you simply replace the channel entries tag with the low reorder tag. For example replace this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="newsletters" disable="member_data|category_fields"}
    {!-- YOUR NEWSLETTER --}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

With this:

```
{exp:low_reorder:entries set="newsletter_set" disable="member_data|category_fields"}
    {!-- YOUR NEWSLETTER --}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Notice that the channel parameter in the exp:channel:entries tag is replaced with the name of your low reorder set in the exp:low_reorder:entries tag.

According to the documentation here: http://gotolow.com/addons/low-reorder/docs/tags all of the parameters you can use in exp:channel:entries are supported:

"The Entries tag supports all channel:entries parameters and variables. Any filters will be overridden by the given parameters, unless you set force_set_params to yes. The dynamic parameter is automatically set to no, if not explicitly set to yes."

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot, this is a permissions issue. Make sure you are logged in as SuperAdmin, then you can assign permissions to other member groups per Reorder Set.

Right now, it looks like the member group "Editor" belongs to doesn't have the permissions to reorder entries nor edit the sets themselves.